# What kind of action is the Investiture of the Erinyes' beckoning?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, actions

> While the spell is in effect, the subject can beckon a creature it can see clearly, forcing it to approach unless the creature succeeds on a Will save against the spell's save DC.

What kind of action do I need to spend on this beckoning? I cannot find it anywhere in the spell description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I would say it takes a standard action.

From "Actions in combat",

> A standard action allows you to **do something**, most commonly make an attack or cast a spell.

Consider this: you are turning your attention to a creature and forcing it to approach. This should require some amount of effort. Since it is a spell effect, it's safe to assume it would require a comparable amount of effort as would concentrating on an active spell take, and concentrating on a spell is a standard action.

Approaching from another perspecitve, any unusual type of action is normally spelled out in description ("as a free action, you can..."). If it doesn't and you need to "do something", it would default to a standard action instead.